# How do you benchmark UICollectionView cell performance?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, benchmarking

I have a collection view cell with cell rounding, shadows etc that the designer insists on and have tried a few different techniques to make it better like rasterisation, shadow masks. I still get some dropped frames and can look in instruments to get a general picture of FPS but is there a way to benchmark it to get a consistent FPS with a fast and fixed scroll speed, without any manual intervention?

I've tried a technique based off **CADisplayLink** and UITests as linked in below but I dont get a very fast scroll test using `collectionView.swipeUp()`.

http://thisiskyle.me/posts/measuring-ios-scroll-performance-is-tough-use-this-to-make-it-simple-and-automated.html

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments and profiling to see where your performance issue is? Most of the time performance has nothing to with drawing and everything to do with slow code being called when the table view cell is being created.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using reuseIdentifier for the cells? Also too complicated autolayout can make scrolling slow.  (I do not think that the problem lyes in shadows or corners)